# Adding / removing components dynamically in JSF2 / Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, partial-page-refresh

I have found similar questions while doing some research, but none of them really addressed my problem.

I have a form with some input criteria and a submit button. When clicking submit, a primefaces datatable is populated below the form with some results. What I need is to show different tables depending on the data entered without refreshing the whole page. E.g. if a user enters Person as a value in the form, results for Person table are shown. However, if the user selects Company, results for Company are shown with its corresponding columns.

Comment: "without refreshing the whole page" then use the update primefaces attribute on ajax requests to update only specific components instead of  the whole site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make use of `update` attribute to update the datatable. Further you can use [`<p:columns>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf) to generate columns dynamically.

```html
<p:inputText value="#{bean.input}" />
<p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" update="table" />

<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{bean.model}" var="item">
    <p:columns value="#{bean.columns}" var="column">
        <h:outputText value="#{item[column]}" />
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

with something like:

```java
public void submit() {
    model = populateModelBasedOn(input);
    columns = populateColumnsBasedOn(input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, but model is a list with a single HashMap which contains the key/value pairs for the table. Then the brace notation is used to access each value of the hashmap by the column name (item[column])? Quite new to jsf here as you can see :)

Comment: It can also be just a javabean. The brace notation allows you to use dynamic property names. The `#{bean.columns}` just contains the property names.